# python lxml xpath returning escape characters in list with text

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Before last week, my experience with Python had been very limited to large database files on our network, and suddenly I am thrust into the world of trying to extract information from html tables.

After a lot of reading, I chose to use lxml and xpath with Python 2.7 to retrieve the data in question.  I have retrieved one field using the following code:

```
xpath = "//table[@id='resultsTbl1']/tr[position()>1]/td[@id='row_0_partNumber']/child::text()"
```

which produced the following list:

```
['\r\n\t\tBAR18FILM/BKN', '\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t']
```

I recognized the CR/LF and tab escape characters, I was wondering how to avoid them?

Answer (score 1):

Those characters are part of the XML document, which is why they are being returned.  You can't avoid them, but you can strip them out.  You could call the `.strip()` method on each item returned:

```
results = [x.strip() for x in results]
```

This would strip leading and trailing whitespace.  Without seeing your actual code and data it's harder to give a good answer.

For example, given this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from lxml import etree

with open('data.xml') as fd:
    doc = etree.parse(fd)

results = doc.xpath(
    "//table[@id='results']/tr[position()>1]/td/child::text()")

print 'Before stripping'
print repr(results)

print 'After stripping'
results = [x.strip() for x in results]
print repr(results)
```

And this data:

```
<doc>
  <table id="results">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Description</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
      1
      </td>
      <td>
      Bob
      </td>
      <td>
      A person
      </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      2
      </td>
      <td>
      Alice
      </td>
      <td>
      Another person
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</doc>
```

We get these results:

```
Before stripping
['\n\t\t\t1\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\tBob\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\tA person\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t2\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\tAlice\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\tAnother person\n\t\t\t']
After stripping
['1', 'Bob', 'A person', '2', 'Alice', 'Another person']
```